# Equip Phases / Puresteel Paladin

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am unsure whether the "equip ability" can be played as often as I want during one round when using [Puresteel Paladin](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPuresteel%20Paladin%5d), or by simply paying the equip costs.

Example: A creature is equipped with [Whispersilk Cloak](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWhispersilk%20Cloak%5d) and I want it to have other equipments on it. Due to shroud that would at first not be possible.

Can I therefore within the pre-combat phase attach the Cloak onto another creature using the Paladin's ability, then attach the other equipments onto the first creature, and then re-attach the Cloak to that first creature?

Or could it be that I can only equip (or attach equipments) one time during a turn or within a specific phase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can shuffle around euqipment all you want with the Puresteel Paladin, as long as you have at least three artifacts in play.

The only restriction there is to activating the Equip ability, is that you can do it only any time you can play a sorcery (ie on your turn, in a main phase, when the stack is empty).

[The rules](http://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020170825.txt) on Equipment (specifically, the Equip ability) state nothing about how often you can activate it:

> **702.6. Equip**
>
> 702.6a Equip is an activated ability of Equipment cards. “Equip [cost]” means “[Cost]: Attach this permanent to target creature you control. Activate this ability only any time you could cast a sorcery.”
>
> 702.6b For more information about Equipment, see rule 301, “Artifacts.”
>
> 702.6c If a permanent has multiple instances of equip, any of its equip abilities may be activated.